# Spring Data Flow Helm chart: Is there a way to declare creation of applications and tasks within the helm charts?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, spring-data-flow

The only way I am running into is using curl command as per the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.7.1/reference/htmlsingle/#resources-app-registry-post

This uses a curl command to hit the api. Which I can develop a script for, but I would like to set this up within the helm charts so that these tasks and applications are created when the helm chart is deployed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [Spring Cloud Data Flow, Helm Installation, Register prebuilt applications](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/helm/#register-prebuilt-applications), it says:

> Applications can be registered individually using the app register functionality or as a group using the app import functionality.

So, I guess you always need to start the app using Helm Chart and only later register the applications using `app` or REST Endpoint.

Comment: thanks. After a lot of research, this seems to be the only way